# Как обработать массив JSON и сохранить данные в модель, если ответ содержит вложенный массив с различным количеством полей?

Tags: python, json, django

Изучаю Django, и появилась проблема. Есть API стороннего ресурса, методом get, оттуда забираю данные, и приходит ответ, который может содержать различное количество полей, в зависимости от "подтянутого" объекта.

Например:

У меня есть поле `tags_id=models.IntegerField(max_lenght=255)` , но в ответе может случится так, что у одной модели 2, или 3 тега. Как решить эту проблему? Использовать в качестве БД *Postrege*? Или же попробовать библиотеку *JSONFields*?

Я в растерянности, в обычном питоне, это реализуется легко, но тут, я в сомнении. Как сделать проверку на количество определённых данных в объекте, и расширить модель под полученный ответ?

Comment: Или организовать связь many-to-many, если количество тегов модерируется, а пользователь выбирает из существующих.

Comment: @Lecron Теги увы, не модерируются во внешней системе. Их забивает менеджер проекта. Я думал использовать ещё одну модель, конкретно модель тега, и уже эту модель использовать в основной модели. Но тут я понимаю, будет лучше использовать связь один ко многим. Или я ошибаюсь?